# Getting 'missing or invalid option' when running this script

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm getting a 'missing or invalid option' when running this script (The full error is: *ORA-00922: missing or invalid option ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", line 581 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", line 567 ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2127*). The statement in question is "CREATE TABLE manufacturer (m_name VARCHAR2(50), m_id." What should I do to fix it?

```
DROP TABLE vehicles CASCADE constraints;
DROP TABLE suppliers CASCADE constraints;
DROP TABLE manufacturer CASCADE constraints;

CREATE TABLE vehicles
    (VIN        VARCHAR2(17),
     brand      VARCHAR2(20),
     model      VARCHAR2(20),
     color      VARCHAR2(10),
     PRIMARY KEY (VIN, brand, model, color)
    );

CREATE TABLE suppliers
    (s_name     VARCHAR2(20), 
     s_id       VARCHAR2(15), 
     part_id    VARCHAR2(20),
     supply_date    VARCHAR2(15),    
     PRIMARY KEY (s_name, s_id, part_id, supply_date)
    );

CREATE TABLE manufacturer
    (m_name     VARCHAR2(50), 
     m_id       VARCHAR2(15), 
     s_name     VARCHAR2(20),
     VIN        VARCHAR2(17)),
     PRIMARY KEY (m_name, m_id)),
      FOREIGN KEY (s_name) REFERENCES suppliers
        ON DELETE SET NULL
     FOREIGN KEY (VIN) REFERENCES vehicles
        ON DELETE SET NULL
    );


--LOAD DATABASE

INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES ('JM1CW2BL4D0154490', 'Mazda', 'Mazda5', 'Brown');
INSERT INTO suppliers VALUES ('MNAO Supplier', 'MNAO', '308', '01/28/2013');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES ('Mazda Motor Corp', 'MZDAY', 'MNAO Supplier', 'JM1CW2BL4D0154490');
```

Comment: You have a few extra closing parentheses that should not be there, as in `PRIMARY KEY (m_name, m_id))`. Then, the foreign keys definition are not valid SQL: you need to provide the column name(s) in the parent table, as in: `FOREIGN KEY (s_name) REFERENCES suppliers(s_name) ON DELETE SET NULL`. But even so: the foreign keys are malformed: you can only reference a primary key (or a set of unique columns) in the parent table, which is not what you are doing here. You probably need to rethink your design.

Comment: Ah thank you. I didn't catch the parentheses. I fixed the foreign keys too and set up a new design with "CONSTRAINT" recommended by MT0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vehicle Identification Number (VIN) is unique; you don't need any other columns to make a primary key so your `vehicles` table can be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE vehicles(
  VIN   VARCHAR2(17)
        CONSTRAINT vehicles__vin__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  brand VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT vehicles__brand__nn NOT NULL,
  model VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT vehicles__model__nn NOT NULL,
  color VARCHAR2(10)
        CONSTRAINT vehicles__color__nn NOT NULL
);
```

Similarly, you probably want only one column as the primary key in `suppliers` (and should store date values as the `DATE` data type):

```sql
CREATE TABLE suppliers (
  s_name      VARCHAR2(20)
              CONSTRAINT suppliers__s_name__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  s_id        VARCHAR2(15)
              CONSTRAINT suppliers__s_id__nn NOT NULL,
  part_id     VARCHAR2(20)
              CONSTRAINT suppliers__part_id__nn NOT NULL,
  supply_date DATE
              CONSTRAINT suppliers__supply_date__nn NOT NULL
);
```

Then your `manufacturer` table can be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE manufacturer(
  m_name     VARCHAR2(50), 
  m_id       VARCHAR2(15), 
  s_name     VARCHAR2(20)
             CONSTRAINT manufacturer__s_name__fk
               REFERENCES suppliers (s_name) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  VIN        VARCHAR2(17)
             CONSTRAINT manufacturer__vin__fk
               REFERENCES vehicles (vin) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT manufacturer__m_name__m_id__pk PRIMARY KEY (m_name, m_id)
);
```

*(Again, you probably want to change it so only a single column is the primary key.)*

Then you can insert your data:

```sql
INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES ('JM1CW2BL4D0154490', 'Mazda', 'Mazda5', 'Brown');
INSERT INTO suppliers VALUES ('MNAO Supplier', 'MNAO', '308', DATE '2013-01-28');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES ('Mazda Motor Corp', 'MZDAY', 'MNAO Supplier', 'JM1CW2BL4D0154490');
```

(and don't pass dates as strings, use `TO_DATE` or a date literal.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=efdcf1b1421df62ffa1517503f40fd61)*

Comment: Thank you so much! I plan to implement more queries and use this method. I certainly learned something new today.